# DataTables and custom types

Tags: c#, class, datatable, types

I created a class called `CustomData` which uses another one called `CustomOptions` as one of its fields. I want to use the `CustomData` in a `DataTable` as values. Here's a short overview (*simplified, the fields are `private` and the accessors `public`, mostly readonly and the `set` is done by custom methods*);

```
enum CustomDataOptionType
{
 // Some values, not important
}

class CustomOptions
{
 public CustomDataOptionType type { get; }
 public Dictionary<string, string> values { get; }
 // Some Methods to set the values
}

class CustomData
{
 public CustomOptions options { get; }
 // Some Methods to set the options
}
```

So, in the "actual" class that uses the ones above, I create a `DataTable`, using columns that are `typeof(CustomData)`.

But when I try to access the columns, e.g. by

```
DataRow Row = data.Rows.Find("bla");
Row["colmn1"].options; // Not possible
```

Why can't I access the `options`-field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `Row["column1"] returns` "object".
You need cast the value to your type:

```
((CustomData)Row["column1"]).Options.
```

**EDIT:**
If you want handle the *NULL* values, you should use this:

```
CustomData data = Row["column1"] as CustomData;
if ( null != data ) {
    // do what you want
}
```

Or you can use a extension methods for simplify it:

```
public static DataRowExtensionsMethods {
    public static void ForNotNull<T>( this DataRow row, string columnName, Action<T> action ) {
        object rowValue = row[columnName];
        if ( rowValue is T ) {
            action( (T)rowValue );
        }
    }
}
// somewhere else
Row.ForNotNull<CustomData>( "column1", cutomData => this.textBox1.Text = customData.Username );
```

Comment: The code is assuming you are dead sure the type is the correct one at that column.

Comment: If set the DataType of colum to "typeof(CustomData)", then there can be only the "CustomData" and/or the "DBNull" which represents the "NULL" value.

Comment: @ApoY2k: If you can ensure that and/or do like what TcKs mentioned, you are pretty safe :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast it into the type `CustomData`.

`((CustomData)Row["colmn1"]).options`